# Variable distributions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, distribution

I have a Matlab assignment which is very important for my final grade but I'm not sure how to begin. Basically it has 7 clauses that are related to each other but I will ask about the first 3 because I really just want to know how I can approach the assignment and then do the rest on my own.

1. Create a random vector that includes 5 random variables that are statistically dependant.

I looked this up and the only thing I could think of is either using the pdf command or the cdf command. Should I use either one of them? And how can I make sure they are statistically dependant? And since I am not told which distribution to use, is it possible to make Matlab decide that one for me?

2. Show the distribution of each of the random variables on a single plot.

I assume I should just use plot on this one? For this I just need to know how to do the first clause, I guess.

3. Calculate the covariance matrix of the vector. Check what would have happened if the vector had included 5 variables that are statistically independant.

How to I Calculate the covariance matrix? Is there a Matlab command for that?

I really hope you can help me, as I have no idea how to even begin.
Thank you!

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but a search and reading a bit about the Matlab commands  will give you the answers.

Comment: I already did, but I couldn't find the answers so I asked here. Also I think I proved that I searched and tried to find answers of my own before asking.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/examples/simulating-dependent-random-variables-using-copulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) There are many ways to create random variables which are dependent. Perhaps the simplest to make a variable `Y` which is dependent on another `X` is to take a function of `X` and add noise. E.g. let `X` be a Gaussian variable with some mean and variance, then let `Y = X^2 + e` where `e` is a Gaussian variable with mean 0 and any variance. So for your 5 variables: let the first be Gaussian, then let the other 4 be functions of the first plus noise.

(2) Dunno for sure but I think you can use `plot` for that.

(3) `cov` computes covariance if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure - to create variable X, should I use the pdf command like I thought, or should I use other commands? When I searched on how to do it some people suggested using various rand functions. Also, with what you are suggesting, will the other 4 functions be all the same (same value)?

Comment: @Eran To create X, use some function to generate random numbers (`rand` or `nrand`, maybe there are others, it doesn't really matter for your purpose). The other 4 functions can be anything, but it will be more interesting if they are different. Something like: sin, exp, square, and square root, for example.